# Mock Repository but the Repository didn't found [NestJS]

Tags: mocking, nestjs

my unit testing

```
describe('AssetService', ()=>{
    let assetService: AssetService;
    let assetRepository: AssetRepository;

    beforeEach(async () =>{
        const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [AssetService, TenantProfileService, ProfileUserService, 
                TenantsService, UsersService,
                {provide: AssetRepository, useFactory: ()=>({
                    find: jest.fn(()=>[])
                })},
            ],

        }).compile();

        assetService = await module.get(AssetService);
        assetRepository = await module.get(AssetRepository);

    });

    describe('getAssets',()=>{
        it('call assetRepository.find and should return all assets', async ()=>{
            const result = await assetService.findAll(null, null);
            expect(assetRepository.find).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    })
})
```

Hi, I am just trying to mock my repository but I got error. It like my repository never exists. I use jest.fn but it still didn't work.

my code

```
  async findAll(limit:number=50, keyword:string): Promise<Asset[]> {
    let options: FilterQuery<AssetDocument>;
    if (keyword){
      options = {assetName: {$regex: keyword, $options: 'i'}}
    }else{
      options = {}
    }
    return this.assetRepository.find(options, limit);
  }
```

I used mongoose and build own repository

[image]

Comment: make sure that `assetRepository` type is `AssetRepository` class in your `asset.service.ts`

Comment: You might need to use  `getrRepositoryToken(AssetRepository)` if you're using `@InjectRepository(AssetRepository)`

Comment: @MicaelLevi I am sure assetRepository is AssetRepository. 

```

@Injectable()
export class AssetService {
  constructor(
    private readonly assetRepository:AssetRepository,
    private readonly profileService: TenantProfileService
    ){}
```

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I didn't use typeorm. I built my own repository cause I use mongoose

Comment: edit your question to add your `AssetRepository` class then